# I am trying to use a class and display information from a member function. When I compile, I get a no match for operator error

Tags: c++, class

**This is the main file**

```
`#include <iostream>
#include "Date.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{     Date showData;showData.Setday(25);
      showData.Setmonth(12);
      showData.Setyear(2018);
      cout << showData.showAllInt(showData.Getday(),showData.Getmonth(),showData.Getyear());
      cout << showData.strMonthDayYear(showData.Getday(),showData.Getmonth(),showData.Getyear());
      cout << showData.dayStrMonthYear(showData.Getday(),showData.Getmonth(),showData.Getyear());
return 0;
};
```

**This is the header file**

```
`#ifndef DATE_H#define DATE_H
class Date{
private:
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
public:
    Date();
    virtual ~Date();

    int Getday()
    { return day; }
    void Setday(int val);


    int Getmonth()
    { return month; }
    void Setmonth(int val);


    int Getyear()
    { return year; }
    void Setyear(int val)
    {
        year = val;
    }

    void showAllInt(int da, int mo, int yr);
    void strMonthDayYear(int da, int mo, int yr);
    void dayStrMonthYear(int da, int mo, int yr);
};
```

**This is the cpp file for the class**

```
`#include "Date.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Date::Date()
{
//ctor
month=1;day=1;year=1;
}
void Date::Setday(int val)
{   if(val<32 && val>0)
       day = val;
    else
       cout<<"invalid day. Enter an new value."<<endl;
        exit(0);
}

void Date::Setmonth(int val)
{
     if(val<13 && val>0)
        {
         month = val;
        }
    else
        cout<<"invalid month. Enter an new value."<<endl;
         exit(0);
    }
void Date::showAllInt(int da, int mo, int yr)
{
cout<< da<<"/"<<mo<<"/"<<yr;
}
void Date::strMonthDayYear(int da, int mo, int yr)
{     string months[]= {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
       
      cout<< months[mo]<<" "<<da<<", "<< yr<<endl;}void Date::dayStrMonthYear(int da, int mo, int yr){string months[]= {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };cout<< da <<" "<<months[mo]<<" "<< yr<<endl;
}
Date::~Date()
{
//dtor
}`
```

I have tried to change the data types and changing the variable names. The error I get (on line 11) is

error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'void')|

the code should output

12/25/2018

December 25, 2018

25 December 2018

Comment: You appear to be missing at least 1 `}` in the last file.

Comment: Your problem is you are trying to `cout <<` void functions. Which does not sense. If your function returns nothing what to you expect to print?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you try to print the result of your `showAllInt()`, `strMonthDayYear()` and `dayStrMonthYear()` member functions but those functions only return a void. Void is not printable but your functions print the results themselves so if you leave out the `std::cout <<` part, the results should be printed.

But even then your code will not work correctly because of this: `exit(0);`

In the `Setday()` and `Setmonth()` functions you call `exit(0)` outside of the else scope so that it will get called every time your function is call, even when your arguments are correct. For your functions to work you should put `exit(0)` in a scope after the else like this:

```
void Date::Setday(int val)
{
    if (val < 32 && val > 0)
        day = val;
    else
    {
        std::cout << "invalid day. Enter an new value." << '\n';
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed the issue, thank you for the help!